# How to use awk to use blank lines as record separators and to use newlines as field separators?

Tags: awk, files

I have a file that I need to format a certain way. The records in the file have the following format;

```
Record
One

Record
Two
```

Each record is separated by a blank line and each of the fields is separated by a newline. I need the records in the following format;

```
Record:One

Record:Two
```

This is what I currently have;

```
#!/bin/bash

cat File.txt | awk '{ RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS=":"; ORS="\n" } {print $1,$2 }'
```

This code gives this output;

```
:ecord
:one
```

Which is not even close to what I am looking for. Can this be done in one line?

Comment: You need to set the separators *before* processing the records, by making your first block a `BEGIN` block. Also your file may have Windows line endings - if so, try setting `FS=\r\n`

Comment: That seems to be the case, the file did come from a Windows system. The records are now in the correct format but awk only prints the first record and stops, does it need to be forced to keep reading?

Comment: You don't need to use `cat`. Just use the filename as the argument to the `awk` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perl:

```
perl -l -p -e 'BEGIN {$/="";  $\="\n\n"}; s/\n/:/mg' input
```

- `-l` enables perl's automatic processing of record-endings.
- `-p` puts an implicit `while ... print` loop around the script, so that it automatically reads, processes, and then prints each record (similar to awk).
- setting the input record separator (`$/`) to empty with `$/=""` tells perl to read the input in paragraph mode (one or more blank lines separates each record).
- `$\="\n\n"` sets the output record separator to two newlines, so that records are separated by a blank line.
- it then replaces all newlines in each record with a `:`.

This works for any number of fields in each record.  Each line within a record is a separate field.

Example output:

```
$ perl -lpe 'BEGIN {$/=""; $\="\n\n"}; s/\n/:/mg' input 
Record:One

Record:Two
```

note: there is a blank line after `Record:Two`.

Comment: This works, but as a note for anyone who may come upon this question, please be sure to use dos2unix on your source file and any other files you may be working with to avoid issues with formatting. Without doing so this script would not work but did after.

Comment: that's the case for any text files that originate from MS-DOS or Windows.  Unix text tools expect unix line-endings (LF or `\n`), not DOS line-endings (CR-LF or `\r\n`).    unix tools will still see them as text files (because each line ends with an LF) but there will be a carriage-return remaining at the end.  when printed, a carriage return moves the cursor to the beginning of the line (which is why you were getting garbled output like `:ecord`. The cursor was moved and the line was partially overwritten)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
awk NF=NF RS="" FS="\n" OFS=":" ORS="\n"  File.txt

Record:One
Record:Two
```

Comment: What does `NF=NF` do? AFAIK, `NF` would be reset by `awk` as soon as it has read a record. Setting it to the string `NF` does not make sense to me.